Issue with native-base component in react-native:0.73.7
I upgaded my project from react-native:0.68.7 to 0.73.7.
I ran the project: react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 15 Pro Max" and getting the warn message.

warn Package native-base contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "npx react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.

I am using native-base:2.15.2.
How to resolve this issue.
